# Target the child only not the sub-child by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following Markup

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='first'>
    First Child
    <div class='second'>
  Sub-child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and Below is Jquery

```
$('.parent').children().css("color","#00b3ff");
```

In result it changes color of both child,as I want to select the First child only (not by class).

Comment: This is already the case, just that color rule is inherited from parent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
$('.parent').children().css('color', '#00b3ff').find('> div').css('color', 'black')
```

By using '>' the rule will be applied only on the immediate children, rather than all the children (when using .children())

Another thing you need to do is to ensure the child will not inherit the parent's color, can be done by explicitly giving it color.

Here's [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aFvR4/12/)

Comment: what is the difference between http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aFvR4/1 and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aFvR4/2/

Comment: Both of the div tags are children of .parent. By using '>' the rule will apply only on the immidiate child

Comment: @Tomzan Looks carefully both jsfiddle, what is difference by both rendered HTML? {i didn't downvote}  Color is inherited from parent

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round.  He wants to change the colour of `.first`, not `.second` :p

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah, I was just letting him know :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply do it like that, the css properties are inherited by the chidlren - so if you apply a color to `first` it will get inherited by `second` since it is a decedent of `first`

Since we cannot apply style to text nodes a possible solution is to wrap the text node with an element and style it as given below

```
$('.parent > div').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
}).wrap('<span />').parent().css('color', '#00b3ff');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aFvR4/)

Comment: At least someone understands the problem!

Comment: nice way i have also done it ,but in different way http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/aFvR4/7/

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/aFvR4/7/)

```
var sel = $('.parent').children();
var old_color = sel.css('color');
sel.css('color', '#00b3ff');
sel.children().css('color', old_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

No one post it, so, using only CSS:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f9DXd/)

```
.parent > div{
    color:#00b3ff;
}
.parent div div {
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.parent').next('div').css("color","#00b3ff");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(".parent > div:eq(0)").css("color","#00b3ff");
    $(".parent > div:first").css("color","#00b3ff");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.parent').children( '.first' ).css("color","#00b3ff");
```

Comment: The OP has specified "not by class".

Comment: I think that the css style would still fall down to subchildren using this method.